# submit form to the same page with checkbox without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, ajax, onclick, refresh, submit

I want to submit a form without refreshing the page using onClick event on the checkbox.
Here's an example.

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" onClick="this.form.Submit();">
</form>
```

It sends the data I need, but it keeps reloading the page, how can i prevent this ?

Thanks in advance,
Holmsas.

Comment: Learn about `AJAX`, this is the answer.

Comment: I tried some of the ajax post methods, but all of them worked only when there was a submit button. Could someone provide an example how I can do achieve this without it ?

Comment: Do you use\can use jQuery, it's too long without it...

Comment: Right, with jQuery you could use `jQuery.ajax()`. If you absolutely don't want to use jQuery for some reason then there is the *old* way with `xmlhttp` object.

Comment: Yes I do use jQuery. By the way thanks for the quick replies.

Answer (score 0):

A traditional POST always causes a refresh (because your browser must show the response). If you want to avoid this you need to use an Asynchronous technology such as [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29), which is the amalgamation of Javascript and XML.

Many libraries exist to simplify the use of AJAX, [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is just one of them.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit the page using POST a refresh is needed. To prevent a refresh, consider using an ajax call.